# Error message when sending Monero from Trezor HW Wallet after latest upgrade: Cannot deserialize bulletproof rangesig - Sending

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, error-log

Updated Trezor HW wallet to latest version
Updated to gui-win-x64-v0.18.1.0
Running local node

No issues receiving xmr, but receiving above error message when trying to send.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the firmware contains a bug that disallows users to send to an integrated address from their Trezor Monero wallet. Please see other reports here:

https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/issues/2213#issuecomment-1227876081

Fortunately, ph4r05 has fixed the issue and created a pull request:

https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/pull/2479

I am currently not aware of any ETA for the new firmware release, but I'd expect for it to be released shortly.